# packet_write_wait: Connection to xxx port 3591: Broken pipe

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I realise this question was asked before, but I couldn't find a solution to my problem so far. 
I was logged into a remote server using ssh, when I decided to log out using

> sudo pkill -KILL -u user

After that I was not able to connect to the server using ssh. I am getting a prompt asking for the password, which I put in. After that I get

> packet_write_wait: Connection to xxx port 3591: Broken pipe

I already set `ClientAliveInterval 60` and restarted the sshd using `service sshd restart`, without any success.

The server and the client are both running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

killing  your ssh session with the way you describe in your question ...well isn't that great, ie. there are more graceful ways to terminate / logout of an ssh server.

I really like using keyboard shortcuts when I can, and I almost exclusively use,
<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> to gracefully logout of a remote box using ssh.

The below command will also log the current logged in user.

```
exit
```

---

A scenario I often run into is when I login to a remote box and and the session get terminated abruptly, and I can not input any text into my terminal, thus a "hanging / dangling process" to get out of this state, I use the below keyboard shortcut.

<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>